# Adding File Properties such as the Creator or Author

Tags: powershell

As of now I have a script that will pull and export all files that are older than 7 years:

```
get-childitem -Path C:\ -recurse| 
     where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).Addyears(-7)} | 
     Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, @{N='Owner';E={$_.GetAccessControl().Owner}}, @{N='Author';E={$_.GetAccessControl().Author}}| 
     Export-Csv C:\file.csv
```

Now, I need help adding the Creator or Author from the file properties. The `@{N='Author';E={$_.GetAccessControl().Author}}` doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean add? They're already there in your command.

Comment: The @{N='Author';E={$_.GetAccessControl().Author}} doesnt work

Comment: Hint: Are `Creator` and `Author` NTFS file properties?

Comment: Yes they are NTFS file properties. I need the Full Name, LastWriteTime, Owner, and Author  or Creator

Comment: I see `FullName`, `LastWriteTime` (`FileInfo` object) and `Owner` (part of the `FileSecurity` object retrieved using the `GetAccessControl` method) when I inspect file objects. I don't see `Author` or `Creator`. (Unfortunately, wishful thinking doesn't cause desired properties to spring into existence.)

Answer (score 0):

Adjusted so that you're retrieving ACLs properly.  I don't think it's possible to grab the original author, however.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Recurse |
    Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddYears(-7)} |
    Select-Object @( 'FullName'
                     'LastWriteTime'
                      @{ N = 'Owner'
                         E = { (Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).Owner }
                       }
                   ) |
    Export-Csv -Path C:\file.csv
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to pull the 'Last Save By' Property instead of the owner?

Comment: @rehenderson Without [editing auditing settings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130418-00/?p=4623), it doesn't look like you can.

Comment: Is there a way to get the original Author which is different from the Owner?